# Create ClusterRole with non-existent Service Account

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I was creating a ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding in my EKS Cluster, using CloudFormation. So, due to lack of attention, I informed a non-existent ServiceAccount, for example:

[cluster role and cluster role binding example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCjie.png)

However, these resources were created successfully without any warnings or errors.

So, I thought... is this behavior correct? Create unnecessary resources with non-existent attributes.

I noticed this issue, when I tested my application and got 403 Forbidden from k8s, then, I saw the ClusterRole associated with a non-existent ServiceAccount, but, created.

Is there any reason why it allowed the creation?

Do not allow the creation of the resource, because if the ServiceAccount does not exist, this resource will be unnecessary and confusing.

Comment: Create a feature request in the kubernetes project repository, otherwise it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons but the easiest one is that this behaviour allows you to not having to follow an order when creating resources, which means you can potentially parallelise efforts instead of having to serially create your resources in just the right order.

At the end of the day you're responsible for getting the names of your resources right.

Assuming this is intended behaviour, you probably will have bad luck getting this changed in Kubernetes itself so your options are to carry a fork with a custom change or use a validating webhook like explained [here](https://medium.com/swlh/kubernetes-validating-webhook-implementation-60f3352b66a).

Though, the implementation effort is significantly bigger than "just" making sure your resources are named correctly.